# PHP Web Service

Tags: php, .net, web-services

I am new to the world of PHP and coding as those have helped me answer a number of questions I have posted know. I have the opportunity to jump into the deep end however seeing I have no clue about PHP and web services, I am seeking your help. I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction as I have not been able to find any examples nor detailed information regarding it.

Effectively there is a PHP page that needs to pass certain values to a .NET web service i.e. name, email, mobile number and upon the receipt of such information the web service sends out a text message. This is information I have so far

*The Allocation service uses a basic HTTP binding and TransportWithMessageCredential security.*

```
Sample C# code using a reference generated with Visual Studio tooling
Allocation.AllocationServiceV3Client Client = new Allocation.AllocationServiceV3Client();
Allocation.AllocateResult Result;
string VoucherCode;
DateTime ExpiryDate;
string DisplayMessageText;
Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ? ;
Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ? ;
 Result = Client.AllocateToConsumerMobileAndSendSMS(out VoucherCode,
                                                               out ExpiryDate,
                                                               out DisplayMessageText,
                                                               ClientID,
                                                               ClientReference,
                                                               CampaignID,
                                                               ActivityID,
                                                               MobileNumber);
if (Result != Allocation.AllocateResult.Success)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no clue about PHP and web services

First things first, pick your brain up out of the C# soup and sit it out to dry off for a few hours.  PHP is a simple language for simple things.  If you're new to it, you don't want to try and make it do complex things, and you certainly *don't* want to try writing C# style code in PHP.

Let's take "web services" as an example of a "complex" thing.  In some circles, this means horribly designed monstrosities like SOAP.  VS makes it relatively easy to build SOAP bindings to your existing classes, so it's not a painful solution for you.

SOAP is a *very* painful solution for PHP.

> Effectively there is a PHP page that needs to pass certain values to a .NET web service

It sounds like you have an existing web service set up then, correct?

You *could* try and use the [built in SOAP client](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php), but it's an undebuggable and unconfigurable binary blob of horrors that will make you want to kill someone if it doesn't work for you immediately.

---

*Edit: The section below was written incorrectly assuming that both sides were under your control.  As this is not the case, you can disregard the rest of the answer.  I'm leaving it up because it may be valuable to others.*

I would advise a different approach.  Set up an endpoint (URL) in your .NET application that expects the data you've specified as POST values, and have PHP POST the data.  This has the distinct advantage of being *incredibly* simple.  Because you're new to PHP, simple is a big win.

(In other words, ditch the "web service" -- or make a parallel copy if other things consume that service already.)

PHP comes with a service called [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/), a repository of helpful classes.  You can use [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2) to quickly [build the HTTP POST request](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.request.php).  Chances are that it's already installed.  If it isn't, it's easy to install either at the system level using the `pear` command, or locally in your project.

Here's some quick example code copied straight out of the reference guide:

```
$request = new HTTP_Request2('http://www.example.com/your/endpoint/url.foo');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST)
    ->addPostParameter('name', '...')
    ->addPostParameter('email', '...')
    ->addPostParameter('mobile', '...');
$response = $request->send();
```

You can then [read the response](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.response.php) as needed.

Now, this isn't a perfect solution.  Your C# code mentions a username and password, which I suppose *could* be included in the POST data.  You could also use HTTP authentication (supported by HTTP_Request2) instead.

Comment: @Charles - Thanks. The web service is an external service I have no control over. The C# code is a sample of what they provided with me. The web service expects the parameters I specified i.e name, email, mobile, etc but also requires that I login using a username and password when I make the request. I take it the endpoint would be an example http://www.example.com/your/endpoint/url.svc?wdsl?

Comment: @Peanuts, if you have no control over the third party web service, then you basically have to disregard the entire second half of my post.  Sorry -- I assumed you controlled both halves.  Make sure that SOAP is the underlying service mechanism being used, and try out the SOAP extension that I linked.  I suggest meditation beforehand... and a stress ball.

Comment: @Charles - Is there an alternative such as using nusoap?

Comment: @Peanuts, nusoap up and *died* a few years ago.  While it's been resurrected since then, the people that took it over keep the documentation very well hidden.  I can not vouch for how well it works, but it may well be better than the opaque shop of horrors of the SOAP extension.

Comment: @Charles - Seems like it'll be a nightmare to call a webs ervice using PHP or am I jumping to conclusions?

Comment: @Peanuts, the underlying problem is that [SOAP is an interoperability nightmare](http://wanderingbarque.com/nonintersecting/2006/11/15/the-s-stands-for-simple/).  While the rate of change has slowed lately, some things are still catching up.  For example, certain versions of the .NET SOAP handler *refuse* to accept certain XML Content-Types, such as those that the PHP builtin SOAP client produces, and neither side can be convinced to let the other be correct (i.e. the client can't send a different type, and the server can't ever accept the "wrong" one).  Simple RESTful services are superior.

Comment: @Charles - Would I not be able to use REST to consume the .NET web service?

Comment: @Peanuts, unfortunately that is correct.  Not unless you want to build the SOAP XML yourself.  Don't do that, though.  Down that road lies *madness*.

Comment: @Charles - I am amazed at the level of complexity involved. So when would I be able to use REST if not to consume a web service?

Comment: @Peanuts, I think you might be suffering from a bit of jargon confusion. When I read "web service," I think of a URL that when poked or prodded produces a result. When certain developers read "web service," they're talking about a tool-produced HTTP-based API that is usually SOAP. While both things take place over HTTP, they are vastly different animals. For example, SOAP calls are all about the programming language code that builds the XML that gets sent, while RESTful web services are all about the URL and GET/POST parameters, entirely ignoring the toolset.  (continued)

Comment: It might be worth [reading the Wikipedia article on REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer). Beware that REST is a philosophy-heavy concept for certain groups. If you end up building a RESTful API for a future application of yours, be prepared to take flak from people that insist you're doing it wrong.  Anyway, we're wondering pretty off topic here -- you're stuck in SOAP land.  Good luck, my friend -- I've got to run.

Comment: @Charles - Thanks. That is a fair bit to digest but thanks for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, now from what I understand, C# will make a request to the php page, wich then (in simple html) gives it back some data.

PHP Is made to do some calculation serverside and when it's done it will send the prints and echo's to the client side as html (simple explanation)

If you want to start using php you would be best off getting into the basics by following the tutorials at W3School (http://w3schools.com/php/default.asp)

Then you can use http://php.net as a reference for more functions you might need.

The way you'll want to set it up is for C# to make a request to a page like action.php
And then using a $_GET method to get the data so C# would send a request to 
action.php?userid='456'

Comment: Yikes!  Avoid w3schools' PHP section.  Their tutorial code is prehistoric and full of bad practices and security holes large enough to drive a 747 through.  It is a *bad* starting place, and should be used as an example of how *not* to teach PHP.

Comment: No, the PHP page needs to call the web service which has been developed in C#.